# Escaping SelectParameters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have the following `SQLDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="topicSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings" 
        SelectCommandType="Text" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tbl_Topic WHERE TopicId = @TopicId">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TopicId" QueryStringField="id" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Does ASP.NET escape the `select` parameter for me?  If not, what do I do to make it safer to prevent injections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: in this case, you are fully protected from SQL injection.  That's the whole point for having SQL parameters in this fashion.